# Adding a Day to a Date, based on another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the issue that I am combining two data sets and they have different definitions of midnight. I therefore want to add a day to one of the dataset's for every occurrence of midnight so that they both follow the same date setup.

I have structured my date and time by:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
df['Hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Hour']).dt.strftime('%H:%M')
```

And then I am trying to amend any occurrence of 00:00:00 so that it is one day later:

```
df.loc['Hour' == '00:00:00', 'Date'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.Date) + timedelta(days=1)
```

However i keep raising a KeyError:

```
raise KeyError("cannot use a single bool to index into setitem")
KeyError: 'cannot use a single bool to index into setitem
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Aim:
Input:

```
Date        |  Hour
---------------------
19/06/2016  |  23:30
19/06/2016  |  23:45
19/06/2016  |  00:00
20/06/2016  |  00:15
20/06/2016  |  00:30
```

Output:

```
    Date        |  Hour
    ---------------------
    19/06/2016  |  23:30
    19/06/2016  |  23:45
    20/06/2016  |  00:00
    20/06/2016  |  00:15
    20/06/2016  |  00:30
```

Comment: Can you add data sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) for check midnight and add one day:

```
f['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(f['Date'])
m = f['Hour'] == '00:00'
f['Date'] = f['Date'].mask(m, f['Date'] + pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d')).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Solution with `loc`:

```
m = f['Hour'] == '00:00'
dates = pd.to_datetime(f['Date'])
f.loc[m, 'Date'] = (dates + pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d')).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
#alternative
#f.loc[m, 'Date'] = (dates[m] + pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d')).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Solution with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
m = f['Hour'] == '00:00'
dates = (pd.to_datetime(f['Date']) + pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d')).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
f['Date'] = np.where(m, dates, f['Date'])
```

---

```
print (f)
         Date   Hour
0  19/06/2016  23:30
1  19/06/2016  23:45
2  20/06/2016  00:00
3  20/06/2016  00:15
4  20/06/2016  00:30
```

Within Code:

```
for fname in glob.glob(path):
    fname = fname.replace(r'\2016', '/2016')
    f = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(fname))
    f = f.replace({'Hour': {'24:00:00': '00:00'}})
    f['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(f['Date']).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
    f['Hour'] = pd.to_datetime(f['Hour']).dt.strftime('%H:%M')

    m = f['Hour'] == '00:00'
    dates = (pd.to_datetime(f['Date']) + pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d')).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
    f['Date'] = np.where(m, dates, f['Date'])

    print(fname)
    if a == 0:
        f_2016['Date'] = f['Date']
        f_2016['Hour'] = f['Hour']
        a = 1
    f_2016 = pd.merge(f_2016, f, on=['Date', 'Hour'])
    print(pd.DataFrame.head(f_2016, n=100))
```

Comment: The mask solution throws an error saying that it needs to be a str rather than a Timedelta

Comment: The loc solution gives the date the incorrect way round: `31/01/2016 23:15
31/01/2016 23:30
31/01/2016 23:45
02/01/2016 00:00
01/02/2016 00:15
01/02/2016 00:30
`

Comment: @MaskedMonkey - I changed second solution. What is your pandas version ?

Comment: Pandas version is 0.20.3

Comment: @MaskedMonkey - i test it in `pandas 0.22.0`, working nice.

Comment: @MaskedMonkey - Added new version with `np.where`, this should working nice.

Comment: I've upgraded my pandas to 0.22.0, it works nicely in the numbers above 12 but inverts the change in numbers less than 12: `01/01/2016  23:45
02/01/2016  00:00
01/02/2016  00:15`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167271/discussion-between-maskedmonkey-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 1):

My advice is not to separate Date & Time unless you must.

You can test whether your time is midnight by testing your `datettime` column to a normalized version:

```
import pandas as pd

f = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2018/01/01 15:00', '2018/01/02 00:00']})

f['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(f['Date'])
f.loc[f['Date'] == f['Date'].dt.normalize()] = f['Date'].apply(pd.DateOffset(1))

#                  Date
# 0 2018-01-01 15:00:00
# 1 2018-01-03 00:00:00
```

You can adapt this solution if you really must keep time separate:

```
f = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2018/01/01', '2018/01/02'],
                  'Hour': ['15:00', '00:00']})

f['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(f['Date'])
mask = pd.to_datetime(f['Date'].astype(str)+' '+f['Hour']) == f['Date']

f.loc[mask, 'Date'] = f.loc[mask, 'Date'].apply(pd.DateOffset(1))
```